# complete vs. simple i/o lua

Tags: io, lua

I am trying to write a program to analyze data from a simulation. Since the simulation software I am using is what is running the Lua program, I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I am probably making a programming error.

I am struggling with the difference between using the simple and complete I/O models. I have a block of code, which works, and looks like this:

```
io.output([[filename_and_location]]) 
function segment.other_actions
    if ion_splat ~= 0 then io.write(ion_px_mm, "\n") end
    io.close()
end
```

Note: ion_splat and ion_px_mm are pre-determined variables that take on number values. This code is run over and over again throughout the simulation.

Then I decided to try achieving the same thing using the complete I/O model like this:

```
 f = io.open([[file_name_and_location]],"w")   
 function segment.other_actions ()
    if ion_splat ~= 0 then f:write(ion_py_mm, "\n") end
    f:close()
    end
end
```

This runs, but takes a *lot* longer than the other way. Why is that?

Comment: Why are you closing the file each time `segment.other_actions` is called?

Comment: Global variables are *not* the best way to pass parameters to functions.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:

```
for i = 1, 1000 do
   io.output("test.txt")
   io.write("some data to be written\n")
   io.close()
end
```

Example 2:

```
for i = 1, 1000 do
   local f = io.open("test.txt", "w")
   f:write("some data to be written\n")
   f:close()
end
```

There is no measurable difference in the execution time.

The latter approach is usually preferable because the used file is identified explicitly.

Comment: Opening and closing the file repeatedly is never the preferable approach if it can be avoided.

Comment: @EtanReisner You are right, of course. My intention was to show that there is nothing wrong in the object interface to file services in Lua.

Comment: Sure, you just showed that in the opposite direction from the way I would have gone so I figured I would explicitly point out that the extra work in the loop should, in general, be avoided.

Comment: Well the reason I put the close in is because my program tells me there are "too many files open" if I don't. I'm also not sure why it does that.

Comment: I would expect it to open one file, and then keep writing stuff to that one.